# Making text input editable and non-editable on clicking Submit button using JQuery

Tags: jquery, html

I have a requirement where I need to populate results on text input fields from database when submitting a form using "submit" button and at the same time **make the input fields non-editable**. I currently have a JQuery function to do this:

```
$(function(){
    $(".makeEditable").click(function(){
        $('input:text').removeAttr("readonly");    
    });
    $(".makeNonEditable").click(function(){
        $('input:text').attr("readonly", "readonly");    
    });               
})
```

This function works fine when I test it with a button:

```
<input type="button" value="Make Non Editable" class="makeNonEditable" />
```

However, This isn't working with submit button:

```
<input type="submit" value="Search" class="makeNonEditable"/>
```

So, I don't understand why it doesn't work with submit button but works with normal button.
Any help will be greatly appreciated

Comment: What happens when you click on the submit button ?

Comment: Are you submitting the form programmatically? Post some of your actual HTML.

Answer (score 1):

From your post it seems that both of your button has same class `makeNonEditable`

You can set `readonly` attribute to your text field as default

```
<input type="text" value="" readonly="readonly">
```

Submit button should change to:

```
    $(function() {
       $(".makeEditable").click(function() {
            $('input:text').removeAttr("readonly");
       });
       $(".makeNonEditable").click(function(e) {

                // If you submit the for without ajax
                // then just make the text field default readonly="readonly"

            // OR

                // If you submit the form using ajax then use
                // $('input:text').removeAttr("readonly");
                // within success function
       });
   });
```

Comment: you have added `e.preventDefault()` - My comment was telling you to need to pass the `e` to the function ... nothing more, nothing less ... (your code still doesnt work though ... test it)

Comment: Thanks, using e.preventDefault() did make the field non-editable but now the submit button isn't retrieving any result from database. The normal button was just for test purpose, submit button is the one that submits form to retreive result from database and at the same time make the input field non-editable.

Comment: on removing e.preventDefault() however doesn't make the input field non-editable. It retrieves results but the input field remains editable.

Comment: @theCodeParadox which solution?

Comment: @theCodeParadox This is making fields non-editable but not submitting the form to retrieve results

Comment: @Sujal it will not submit the form if the text field value is empty and you need to place buttons and text field within a form. but if you need to submit though the field is empty then try with `setTimeout()`.

Comment: @theCodeParadox What I wan't is to submit the form first to retrieve result and then make the field non-editable. However, the code is preventing the form from submitting and only making the fields non-editable.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it is the case, but the submit type sends the data of a form and reloads the page.
Try to use:

```
$('#yourForm').submit(function(){
  // do something...
});
```